# Product Page blank

Tags: magento2, product, blank

I recently upgraded some Symfony packages through composer and did basic upgrade commands (setup:upgrade, setup:di:compile, setup:static-content:deploy, cache:clean).
Suddenly, my product pages come up blank.
Every other page works fine.
The system.log shows

```
 main.CRITICAL: TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageFactory::getLabel() must be of the type string, null given, called in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ImageFactory.php on line 171 and defined in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ImageFactory.php:117
```

When I view the source code of a product page, it shows something like this

```
  <meta property="og:type" content="product" /><meta property="og:title" content="2011&#x20;Nitro&#x20;Z6&#x20;&#x20;-&#x20;Hull&#x20;Only" /><meta property="og:image" content="An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details.
```

I am using a custom theme, and it does have a view.xml file. I've tried disabling modules that effect the frontend, with no change.

Has anyone had this issue, or do you have any idea on what I can do to fix this?

Magento 2.4.1

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: It's not caused by any of my code, I disabled it to test

Comment: you can check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Check file etc/view.xml in your custom theme.The root cause of problem not related with any modules installed. If you don't have you need create new file with same name. Content you can copy from blank or luma depend on which theme that you want to inheritance

Example file in blank theme
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/design/frontend/Magento/blank/etc/view.xml#L67
This file is mandatory for each theme where you define essential config work for your theme